# JasperReports 4.x: How to use JRDocxExporter with old version of engine

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a compatibility  problem of JasperReports w. r. t. JDK version. I have been actually using `JDK 1.8` and `JasperReports 6.4.0` which provides the `SimpleExporterInput` Class for generating MS Word (.DOCX) files such as :

```
JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(outputFile)));
```

Due to the production environment's technical requirements I have to compile and run my project using `JDK 1.6`. Therefore using an earlier version of JasperReports such as `4.6.0` or `4.5.0` do not provide the `SimpleExporterInput` class which I do need for my `JRDocxExporter` object. Is there any solution to circumvent this problem please?

Answer (score -1):

The old and **deprecated** way is to use *[JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#JASPER_PRINT)* and *[JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)* parameters .

Example of exporting with help of *JRDocxExporter* with old versions of *JasperReports* (4.5, for example):

```
JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, destinationFileName);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: could you please take a look at this for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808607/how-to-use-initial-value-expression-in-jasper-reports-studio-to-add-value-to-onl