# How to use Initial Value Expression in Jasper Reports Studio to add value to only the first row?

Tags: variables, jasper-reports

My understanding of the initial value expression in Jasper Reports Studio is that it, the said value should be the first value. So I did set it to:

```
$F{rptran_units}.add(new BigDecimal(200))
```

and the expression for my variable to

```
$F{rptran_units}
```

and made my calculation sum.

This is because I want the first value of my variable expression to be have 200 added to it and subsequent values to continue summing without repeatedly adding 200. I guess I might not be going about it in the right way. I would appreciate some clarification on how I could achieve this using the initial value expression or any other method that would help me achieve my aim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have slight misunderstanding what the initial value expression is used for, in your example it will not be used during the computation of the sum of `$F{rptran_units}`, it will only have that value before the computation of variable starts (first iteration of the detail band).

The initial value is:

> the value assumed from the variable at the beginning, before the first computation of its expression - see [Jasper Reports Variables](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/variables)

but this does not mean that the variable start with this value if you like to compute a sum on a field, actually it is not passed to the compute engine and it will only be used if you use the variable (itself) in the expression as example `$V{variable1}+5` in the above link

However the solution to your specific problem (add 200 to the current sum of `$F{rptran_units}`) is very simple, just add 200 to the variabile before displaying the value.

**Example**

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d7a0eb2f-0664-46ec-91f1-02d6de303c18"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SumOfRptran_units}.add(new BigDecimal(200))]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Another solution is to add another variabile that adds 200 to this variable and use this.

```
<variable name="SumAdd200" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{SumOfRptran_units}.add(new BigDecimal(200))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```